# Problem with async/await with FileReader in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, async-await, filereader

I'm using FileReader in a Vue.js project, and I have a problem with this code:

```
async uploadDocuments(files) {
    for (let file of files) {
        let fileName = file.name;
        let fileContent;
        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = async () => {
            fileContent = reader.result;
            await this.submitFile(fileContent, fileName, fileType)
                .then(/* THEN block */)
                .catch(/* CATCH block */);
        };
        reader.onerror = (error) => { console.warn(error); };
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
    console.log("COMPLETED");
}

async submitFile(fileContent, fileName, fileType) {
    // this function should handle the file upload and currently contains a timeout
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 3000));
}
```

This is the desired execution order (example with two files):

1. (wait 3s)
2. THEN block (file 1)
3. (wait 3s)
4. THEN block (file 2)
5. COMPLETED

But this is the actual execution order:

1. COMPLETED
2. (wait 3s)
3. THEN block
4. THEN block

The "THEN block" is correctly executed after the timeout, but the execution of the code in the `for` loop continues without waiting the execution of the `onload` function.

How can I make the reader asynchronous? I tried many solutions (such as wrapping the `for` loop in a promise and putting the `resolve()` function inside `.then()`) but none of them works.

Comment: Why read the file content into memory and upload them as base64? that is the worst. ~3 more bandwidth unnecessary processing, not enough RAM to handle large files. just append the files onto a [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) and upload that instead as a `application/multipart-formdata`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I'd recommend to "promisify" the Reader thing and then use `Promise.all` until all the files are uploaded.

```
uploadDocuments = async (event, files) => {
  const filePromises = files.map((file) => {
    // Return a promise per file
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = async () => {
        try {
          const response = await this.submitFile(
            reader.result,
            file.name,
            fileType
          );
          // Resolve the promise with the response value
          resolve(response);
        } catch (err) {
          reject(err);
        }
      };
      reader.onerror = (error) => {
        reject(error);
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    });
  });

  // Wait for all promises to be resolved
  const fileInfos = await Promise.all(filePromises);

  console.log('COMPLETED');

  // Profit
  return fileInfos;
};
```

Comment: Thank you, this works! I have one more problem now. I replaced the timeout with the actual upload code, `axios.post(...)`, and I need to execute the `/* CATCH block */` in the case that the post should fail. I tried with `axios.post(...).then(...).catch((err) => Promise.reject(err))` but I think that it's wrong and it does not work with your `Promise.all()`. Do you have suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: Nice, please consider marking as resolved.
You could wrap `const response = await this.submitFile(...)` in a try/catch block and call `reject` in the catch.

Comment: Life saver. Can't believe the answer was in plain sight. Nice.

Answer (score -4):

Try this.

Add await before the `reader.onload` it will hold until then or catch block execute successfully

````js
async uploadDocuments(event) {
    for (let file of files) {
        let fileName = file.name;
        let fileContent;
        let reader = new FileReader();
        await reader.onload = async () => {
            fileContent = reader.result;
            await this.submitFile(fileContent, fileName, fileType)
                .then(/* THEN block */)
                .catch(/* CATCH block */);
        };
        reader.onerror = (error) => { console.warn(error); };
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
    console.log("COMPLETED");
}

async submitFile(fileContent, fileName, fileType) {
    // this function should handle the file upload and currently contains a timeout
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 3000));
}```
````

Comment: `reader.onload` is an event handler, it doesn't make sense to try and add `await`